# Pixmap shared between threads in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qpixmap, qmutex

I've got a main GUI class and another Worker class: the first copes with GUI things (drawing a `QPixmap` into a `QGraphicsScene`), the second with computations thing (drawing `QLine`s and `QPoint`s onto that `QPixmap`). 
The two classes run in two different threads.
When I create the `Worker` thread, I pass the address of the GUI's `QPixmap` to the `Worker` class, so they share the same object.

The `QPixmap` is modified in the `Worker` class, and drawn in the `GUI` class. Even if I didn't have any problem, I decided to use a `QMutex` to ensure my program wouldn't try to access the `QPixmap` while it was being drawn. Now, in order to do this, I have a `QMutex` shared between GUI class and `Worker` class (`Worker` class has again a pointer to the GUI's `QMutex`). Whenever I read or modify the `QPixmap` I lock the `QMutex`.

Is this a valid approach? I never got errors so far, but I wonder if it is logically correct and whether Qt provides a better way to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Qt5 thread-safety page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html):

> QPainter can be used in a thread to paint onto QImage, QPrinter, and
>   QPicture paint devices. Painting onto QPixmaps and QWidgets is not
>   supported.

So the official line is no, you should not be modifying a QPixmap outside of the main thread.  You may be "getting lucky" in that it happens to work on your current platform under your current use case, but Qt doesn't guarantee that it will work.

A safer approach might be to have your worker thread draw into a QImage object instead, and then when the GUI thread wants to update the GUI, it can grab and draw the latest version of the QImage object (using mutexes or some other mechanism to make sure that the worker thread isn't simultaneously updating the QImage).

Comment: So, if I use a QImage instead of a QPixmap, will my approach be valid?

Comment: Instead of using a QMutex, just have the worker thread emit a signal with the latest QImage as a parameter, like: newImageCreated(QImage image); This is automatically thread-safe thanks to Qt's Queued connections, and since QImages are implicitly shared, the data isn't actually copied. This is much simpler conceptually than manually locking using a mutex.

Answer (score 2):

I agree according to the documentation, it's not allowed to use QPixmap in a worker thread. However, according to the code.

The constructor checks if it's in the main thread. If it's not in the main thread, it checks for a feature called ThreadedPixmap. If enabled, it will continue without problem. As far as I can see, ThreadedPixmap is supported on all platforms, so it seems possible to use QPixmaps on other threads.